# Copying one structure to another and Effect of changing one on Another

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct node
{
    int a;
    char *p;
};
int main()
{
    struct node X,Y;
    char s[5] = "Adam";
    char t[5] = "Jack";
    X.a = 5;
    X.p = s;
    Y = X;
    Y.a = 10;
    strcpy(Y.p,t);
    printf("%d %s\n",X.a,X.p);
    printf("%d %s\n",Y.a,Y.p);
    return 0;
}
```

In this Question , Structure X has "a=5" and "P pointing to Adam". and then this is copied to another structure Y. and changes are made to Y. 
But when strcpy(Y.p,t) is done .

OUTPUT IS :

```
5 Jack
10 Jack
```

This change is supposed to be only in Y , but these changes are also reflected for X. How so ?

MY question is "How does changing one structure member have effect on another when they are copied " ?

Comment: Well, i think that is a good question.

Comment: Well, they're both pointing to the same thing, then you change that same thing by `strcpy`ing over it.

Comment: Even some 37,000+ user got confused on this one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initialized `Y` as copy of `X`.  That means it contains the same pointer in the `p` field - you didn't ever change that.

When you do the `strcpy`, you're writing the contents of `t` overtop of `s`.

You're lucky you picked two 4-letter names...

Comment: so can i say a Y.p and X.p have same address ?

Comment: No, `Y.p` and `X.p` have different addresses. They are pointers, though, and they both *point to the same address.*

Comment: sir! yeah on changing size of S and T.i can observe the over topping thing ! thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 5):

```
strcpy(Y.p,t);
```

`Y.p` value is the same as the value of `s`. So the above function call is actually the same as:

```
strcpy(s, t);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the character pointer p of both structures X and Y **points to the same memory location**.

so strcpy changes the data for both X and Y